# Meaning of "It was a shortcut for her. She entered at ease within its complexity, at home in song and in feeling."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm not a native speaker and I've been watching a documentary about Marilyn Monroe, where this monologue appeared.

> She searched everywhere, in life and books. She liked poetry. **It was a shortcut
>   for her. She entered at ease within its complexity, at home in song and in feeling.**

Could anyone please explain to me, how can I understand the part in bold letters? Does it mean that poetry was an alternative route for searching meaning of life? And how can I understand the "at home in song and in feeling" part?

Answer (score 1):

"Shortcut" is used metaphorically.  It means, roughly, "easy way into x".  And poetry can be complex, but that didn't bother her.  She was comfortable with it.  "At home" is another metaphor, meaning "comfortable".

The precise intended meaning of "in song and in feeling" is unclear (a bit poetic, it is), but suggests that poetry gave her "a song in her heart" (another metaphor).

Answer (score 0):

You understand it correctly: alternate, faster, easier: *The street was clogged with traffic, so I took a shortcut through the woods.*

There, *at home* means *comfortable*:

- Make yourself at home.
- She rarely felt at home with herself.
- I never feel at home in a tux.